# Ubuntu 18 does not boot after windows 10 update (dual boot) - ubuntu in emergency mode

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot

I have dual boot in my laptop(Ubuntu 18+W10). Yesterday night I updated Windows10, and today Ubuntu has problems to boot. When I select ubuntu in the Grub menu, it enters the emergency mode and can't boot.

Both windows and ubuntu are installed in a ssd unit, and there is another hdd just for the files, which is in exFAT so it can be seen by both OS. Here is what I see after selecting Ubuntu in the Grub:

[image]

(I tried to take the best picture I could, sorry)

Fast boot in W10 is disabled as I have read in some questions. A couple of times it managed to boot after rebooting from windows, but not anymore. I have read a lot online but not idea what's going on. Could anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Does it work from a cold boot? Also please explain what do you mean by "select the Ubuntu *partition*"? You're supposed to select Ubuntu from the Grub menu (and that Grub menu comes from the EFI entry "Ubuntu"). What's "security mode"? What exactly are you seeing? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: If you get out of this, well and good. Otherwise, life is so much easier with virtual machines. Virtualize your least used system.

Comment: I have just edited it with the information. I meant emergency, no security mode. Sorry @ChanganAuto

Comment: Its that secondary drive that might have caused this, is it possible to modify your Ubuntu18 setup so it doesn't auto mount it on boot?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I saw the failed but I dind?t know that it prevents the system from booting. I had a line in the fstab to mount it. Do you know how I should  modify it from the emergency mode?

Comment: `mount -n -o remount,rw /` I think, to mount your root partition when you drop down to a shell, try editing then

Comment: Nothing worked. I ended up installing Ubuntu again. Thanks everybody for the tips